# How to use different buttons with a same method for different results?

Tags: swift, uibutton, uiimage

I have a square of four different images, two at the top and two at the bottom to be displayed after being loaded from the image library.

Each image view is associated to its personal button, that is going to use the same method that goes into the user library to pick up an image.

How can I use four different buttons with the same method to display the image loaded at its proper location?

Can I make a model to execute this behaviour?

Thanks

```
@IBOutlet weak var topLeftImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var topRightImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var bottomLeftImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var bottomRightImage: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var topLeftButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var topRightButtom: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var bottomLeftButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var bottomRightButton: UIButton!

@IBAction func loadTopLeftImage(_ sender: Any) {
    loadPhotoLibrary()
}

@IBAction func loadTopRightImage(_ sender: Any) {
    loadPhotoLibrary()
}

@IBAction func loadBottomLeftImage(_ sender: Any) {
    loadPhotoLibrary()
}

@IBAction func loadBottomRightImage(_ sender: Any) {
    loadPhotoLibrary()
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

    if let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage {


        topLeftImage.image = image

    }
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}


func loadPhotoLibrary() {

        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerController.SourceType.photoLibrary
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false

        self.present(imagePicker, animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create subclass of `UIImagePickerController` and add variable `completionHandler` with parameter of type `UIImage?`

```
class YourPicker: UIImagePickerController {
    var completionHandler: ((UIImage?) -> ())?
}
```

then add parameter to your `loadPhotoLibrary` function which will represents `UIImageView` you want to change its `image`. Also set its completion handler: you want to change `image` of certain ImageView

```
func loadPhotoLibrary(setImageView imageView: UIImageView) {

    let imagePicker = YourPicker() // don't forget to initialize subclass

    imagePicker.delegate = self
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerController.SourceType.photoLibrary
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = false

    imagePicker.completionHandler = { image in
        if let image = image { // if you just dismiss picker, you don't want to delete previous image
            imageView.image = image
        }
    }

    self.present(imagePicker, animated: true)
}
```

now in picker's delegate method downcast `picker` as `YourPicker` and call completion with value for key `UIImagePickerController.InfoKey` casted to `UIImage?` (if its value is `nil`, doesn't matter, it just doesn't set `image` of ImageView)

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

    if let myPicker = picker as! YourPicker {
        myPicker.completionHandler!(info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage)
    }
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

then just in actions of buttons call your `loadPhotoLibrary` method like this

```
@IBAction func loadTopLeftImage(_ sender: Any) {
    loadPhotoLibrary(setImageView: topLeftImage)
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

1- 
If youre using Storyboard, control and drag all your buttons to the same method.
If youre adding a target for each button, show all the selectors to the same method.

2- Add tag:
In storyboard -> your button(s) -> give each one a unique tag
In code add button.tag = uniqueTag

3-
In your universal method you can use a switch (sender.tag) for each button