# Checking which gestureRecognizer was pressed

Tags: ios, swift, image, uigesturerecognizer

I use `gestureRecognizer` with `UIImageView`. And I have two `UIImageView`. Me need upload image in both `UIImageView`. For opening `UIImagePickerController()` I use `gestureRecognizer` on both `UIImageView`.

So me need upload image in different `UIImageView` in `func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any])`

How I can upload image from library?

It's my code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var mainPhotoImageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var addImageView: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    configureGestureRecognizer()

}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    let chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage
    if chosenImage != nil {
        logoImageView.image = chosenImage
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

@objc func addLogoHall(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    let picker = UIImagePickerController()
    picker.delegate = self
    picker.allowsEditing = true
    picker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
    present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

@objc func addMainPhoto(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    let picker = UIImagePickerController()
    picker.delegate = self
    picker.allowsEditing = true
    picker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
    present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func configureGestureRecognizer() {
    let addHallLogo = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(AddPhotoAndLogoViewController.addLogoHall(_:)))
    logoImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    logoImageView.addGestureRecognizer(addHallLogo)
    let addMainPhotoImage = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(AddPhotoAndLogoViewController.addMainPhoto(_:)))
    mainPhotoImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    mainPhotoImageView.addGestureRecognizer(addMainPhotoImage)
}
```

So in `func imagePickerController` me need detect which `gestureRecognizer` was used. Or maybe have alternative opportunity to do it?

Comment: Hi! I recently answered to very similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53837690/10253094, you can look to my answer and maybe it'll help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can add diffrent tag for pickers like this way:**

```
@objc func addLogoHall(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    let picker = UIImagePickerController()
    picker.delegate = self
    picker.allowsEditing = true
    picker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
    picker.view.tag = 1
    present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

@objc func addMainPhoto(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    let picker = UIImagePickerController()
    picker.delegate = self
    picker.allowsEditing = true
    picker.view.tag = 2
    picker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
    present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

And then you can identify by this tag like this way:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    let chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage
    if chosenImage != nil {
       if(picker.view.tag == 1) {
          logoImageView.image = chosenImage
        } else {
          mainImageView.image = chosenImage
        }

        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While Jogendar's answer is good, I see one pitfall. The if-else will grow as the number of image view instances increase in your view controller file. This might get messy and unnecessarily large quickly. Might I suggest an alternative solution:

```
class ImageSelectionController: NSObject, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    weak var delegate: ImageSelectionControllerDelegate?
    private weak var imageView: UIImageView?
    private weak var presentingViewController: UIViewController?

    // MARK: - Initialization
    init(withImageView imageView: UIImageView?, andPresentingViewController viewController: UIViewController?) {
        self.imageView = imageView
        self.presentingViewController = viewController
    }

    // MARK: - Public
    func presentImagePickerController(withConfigurationHandler handler: ((UIImagePickerController) -> Void)? = nil) -> Void {
        let picker = UIImagePickerController()
        picker.allowsEditing = true
        picker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        handler?(picker)
        picker.delegate = self
    }

    // MARK: - UIImagePickerController
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        let chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage
        self.imageView?.image = chosenImage
        self.delegate?.controller(self, didFinishPickingImage: chosenImage, forImageView: self.imageView)
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}

protocol ImageSelectionControllerDelegate: AnyObject {
    func controller(_ controller: ImageSelectionController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage?, forImageView: UIImageView?) -> Void
}
```

// ---- Your View Controller ---- //

```
@IBOutlet weak var logoImageView: UIImageView?
@IBOutlet weak var mainPhotoImageView: UIImageView?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    configureGestureRecognizer()

}

@objc func addLogoHall(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    let controller = ImageSelectionController.init(withImageView: self.logoImageView, andPresentingViewController: self)
    controller.delegate = self
    controller.presentImagePickerController()
}

@objc func addMainPhoto(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    let controller = ImageSelectionController.init(withImageView: self.logoImageView, andPresentingViewController: self)
    controller.presentImagePickerController { (picker) in
        picker.sourceType = .camera
    }
}

// MARK: - ImageSelectionControllerDelegate
func controller(_ controller: ImageSelectionController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage?, forImageView: UIImageView?) {
    print("image picked!")
}
```

Doing it this way, you could put all the `UIImagePickerController` related code in one place and you wouldn't need to have any if-else cases. Again, there is no right or wrong answer and someone might also find some other flaw in my solution. Its just a matter of how you want to structure your code.

Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks, it's good method, but I used method Jogendar Choudhary